# Using constructor of inherited class in constructor

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I am trying to create a constructor that uses a constructor of the base class. I need to set the values of Engine Class within Constructor of Car class.

Here's what I have now:

```
public Car (double brand, double model, double engineCap, double fuelCount, double fuelCap )
: base (SetEngine(engineCap, fuelCount, fuelCap))
    {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;

    }

    private static Engine SetEngine(double engineCap, double fuelCount, double fuelCap)
    {
        Engine engine = new Engine(engineCap, fuelCount, fuelCap);
        return engine;
    }
}
```

My implementation is probably wrong here. Here's the constructor of the  base class:

```
  public Engine(double engineCap, double fuelCount, double fuelCap)
  {
      this.engineCap = engineCap;
      this.fuelCount = fuelCount;
      this.fuelCap = fuelCap;
  }
```

The base class of Car is Engine.

Comment: So what *is* the base class of `Car`? Can you post an [mcve]?

Comment: @nvoigt the base class of Car is Engine.

Comment: Ok, that's somewhat weird, because a car is not an engine, a car *has* an engine. That would be composition instead of inheritance. But anyway, for your syntax question see my answer.

Comment: @user3653415, please do googling. the answer can be found on net. if you cant find then post it here.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the base class constructor with the parameters it expects:

```
public Car (double brand, double model, double engineCap, double fuelCount, double fuelCap ) 
    : base (engineCap, fuelCount, fuelCap)
{
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of Engine first and then pass it as argument to car. or create engine instance in car itself and assign to protected member of base class.